# Is the author's truth table incorrect or is my understanding of the order of operations wrong?

Tags: boolean-algebra

To understand enough about Karnaugh maps to solve [this problem on 4Clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/140) (which hosts problems for the programming language, Clojure), I've studied the wiki articles on K-maps, Boolean Algebra, Set Theory, sets, disjoint sets, math notation, etc.

Partway through I felt I needed more skill in the fundamentals, so I looked for ways to practice my truth tables. Before examining it closely, I took the headers from [the truth table explaining the Distribution Law](https://cnx.org/contents/UZM3jSVd@4.19:3SufcTkz@4/Boolean-Algebra) on an OpenStax piece on Boolean algebra and filled it out. After this I compared my truth table to the author's, when I noticed he had a result that surprised me.

[image: Truth table to explain the Distribution Law]

Compared to mine:

[image: My truth table]

I get that the Distribution Law means $x(y+z)$ is *supposed* to equal $xy+zy$, but I'm not seeing it.

For $x = 0, y = 1,$ and $z = 1$:

1. For $xy+zy$, with:

   1. $x\land y = 0 \land 1 = 0$
   2. $y \land z = 1 \land 1 = 1$
   3. $0 \lor 1 = 1$
2. For $x(y+z)$, this should be $0$:

   1. $0 \land (1 \land 1) =$
   2. $0 \land 1 =$
   3. $0$

The only way to make the first $0$ is: $0 \land (1 \lor 1) \land 0 = 0$.

Is this how Boolean algebra works? Or is it the unlikely case that the author made an error?

Comment: The last column is mislabelled: it should labelled $xy+xz$, not $xy+zy$.

Comment: x(y+z)=xy+xz!  $. $